# Edit file line by line number - C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to edit a .dat file. I want to read a line by line number, turn the content to int, edit and replace it.
like I want to edit line number 23, it says "45" I need to make it "46". How do I do that?

```
ofstream f2;
theBook b;
f2.open("/Users/vahidgr/Documents/Files/UUT/ComputerProjects/LibraryCpp/LibraryFiles/Books.dat", ios::app);
ifstream file("/Users/vahidgr/Documents/Files/UUT/ComputerProjects/LibraryCpp/LibraryFiles/Books.dat");
cout<<"In this section you can add books."<<endl;
cout<<"Enter ID: "; cin>>b.id;
cout<<"Enter Name: "; cin>>b.name;
string sID = to_string(b.id);
string bookName = b.name;
string line;
int lineNumber = 0;
while(getline(file, line)) {
    ++lineNumber ;
    if(line.find(bookName) != string::npos && line.find(sID) != string::npos) {
        int countLineNumber = lineNumber + 4;
        registered = true;
        f2.close();
        break;
    }
}
```

Inside the file:

```
10000, book {
author
1990
20
20
}
```

Comment: What is a line? (Technically)

Comment: What have you tried? What part you don't understand?

Comment: @Thyaris in the file.dat I have data sorted in lines like "name\n id\n" every detail is written in a line

Comment: See my answer :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have the line number, I want to change the data in it

Comment: @WinnStone can u post ur code?

Comment: Are the lines all the same length? Is the file human readable or binary? Does it fit in memory? Why are you using C++ for this?

Comment: @Thyaris added to the question

Comment: Ok, so in your file, no Lines exist. There is just some \n bytes. You have to count the bytes that exist from the beginning to that line in order to write bytes in that line (or better: after the 22nd line break byte)

Comment: @doctorlove it's a class project. I added the file content in the question post

Answer (score 2):

If your file is small (such as under 1GB), you can just read the entire file into memory line-by-line as a `std::vector<std::string>` (Hint: use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)). Then, edit the required line, and overwrite the file with an updated one.

Comment: I recommend reading without hauling the entire file into memory.  Get the technique working first before optimizing.  Reading the entire file into memory is a speed optimization and may waste memory.

Comment: Also, you have to write the entire file again

Answer (score 0):

Iterate Byte for Byte through the file and count line breaks (\n or \r\n on Windows). 
After 22 breaks, insert bytes that say “46”. It should overwrite the existing bytes.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but why would *inserting* a line *overwrite* something? Surely one or the other, not both?

Comment: Because basically what u want the machine to do is write bytes from an offset, not inserting and extending the file in the process.

Comment: sorry I don't understand :D I'm new to c++ would you mind explain it?

Comment: Why read *Byte for Byte*, when you can use `std::getline` and read text line by text line.  Reading one byte at a time is rather inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

If your modifications are the **exact** size of the original text, you can write back to the same file.  Otherwise, you will need to write your modifications to a new file.

Since your file is variable length text, separated by newlines, we'll have to skip lines until we get to the desired line:

```
const unsigned int desired_line = 23;
std::ifstream original_file(/*...*/);
std::ofstream modified_file(/*...*/);
// Skip lines
std::string text_line;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < desired_line - 1; ++i)
{
  std::getline(original_file, text_line);
  modified_file << text_line << std::endl;
}

// Next, read the text, modify and write to the original file
//... (left as an exercise for the OP, since this was not explicit in the post.

// Write remaining text lines to modified file
while (std::getline(original_file, text_line))
{
  modified_file << text_line << std::endl;
}
```

Remember to write your modified text to the modified file before copying the remaining text.

**Edit 1: By record / object**
This looks like an X-Y problem.

A preferred method is to read in the objects, modify the object, then write the objects to a new file.